# how to add a trainable variable to a keras neural notwork model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to create a neural network in Keras (python) as follows:

input  -> .... (dense layers) ... -> output

Furthermore, I want my model to have a trainable variable pi which will be optimized for from the initial value I give.

More precisely, the loss function = MSE(input,output) + f(input,pi) where f is available in nice, analytic form. As a concrete example:

input = n numbers x_i, no intermediate layers, n outputs y_i
with loss function =$$\sum_i (x_i-y_i)^2 + pi^2 * \sum_i x_i^2 $$

Here, pi should me optimized via (S)GD to the value 0.

I tried to implement a custom layer containing the trainable variable pi or pass it as a separate tensor input, but I have not been successful so far in getting the code to work. Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Comment: Could you please restate your question? Could you be more specific about what exactly you are looking for? I am not sure what the question is.

Comment: post your code that you have tried and what issue you are facing in that?